# how to call ylim() repeatedly in matplotlib?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

`ylim()` inputs here are given using std_input. I am on Python 2.7.

```
df = pd.read_csv('sy_1_Mlogi_01081081_1.csv')

df.rename( columns={'Unnamed: 0':'time'}, inplace=True )

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df['Time'] = df['time'].dt.time

df['date'] = df['time'].dt.date

df = df.set_index(['date'])

a = input('starting_Date : ')
b = input('ending_Date   : ')

starting_date = datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
ending_date = datetime.strptime(b, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

df = df.loc[starting_date:ending_date]

x = df['Time']

y = df['d']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(x, y)
long_title = 'Cycling {} to {} \n'
plt.title(long_title.format(starting_date,ending_date))
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('duration')
plt.ylim(ymax=input("Enter Duration Max Limit : "))  
plt.ylim(ymin=input("Enter Duration Min Limit : ")) 
plt.xlabel('Time')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

how can here `ylim()` be put in a `loop` so that I don't have to run program again and again. Simply by inputing the `ylim` values I can get the `plot`. Is this possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_ylim` as follow in a loop.

```
x = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=100, freq='D')
y=range(100)

for i in range(3):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot_date(x, y)
    ax.set_ylim([input("Enter Min Limit : "),input("Enter Max Limit : ")])
```

As a detail :

(1) `ylim` takes in parameters a `[min, max]`.

(2) you can to apply the `set_ylim` to a specific `axes`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any need of for loop. May be I didn't get your question correctly. Why don't you first save the user input values and then assign the limits. You will have to convert to float

```
# Store the user input in variables (as you are doing)
ymin=input("Enter Duration Min Limit : ")
ymax=input("Enter Duration Max Limit : ")
plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)
```

May be you will have to convert you user input into `float/int` depending on your data type.